# Cypress - api response - Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Interception'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, cypress

I need to get a value of parameter returned by an api request which was triggered by a cypress event, more specifically there was an api request triggered by click() and I need to get a value of applicationId parameter returned in the response body so I can set a variable, alias or whatever in order to use this applicationId later in the code (I need to provide it to other endpoint's path that I will be calling with cy.request()

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkcum.jpg)

XHR response body:

```
{
    "applicationId": "abc",
    "accessToken": "xyz"
}
```

My code which I thought would finally work:

```
    cy.intercept("POST", "**/application").as("startApplication");
    cy.wait('@startApplication').then((response) => {
      cy.wrap(response.body.applicationId).as('applicationId')
  })
```

but it gives me an error in IDE:
Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Interception'.ts(2339)
and when Cypress test is run, it's just loading forever.

I've googled a lot and tried many different ways for hours but so far with no success. I'm new to cypress, typescript and even coding in general, so I might be missing even basics concepts.

Answer (score 4):

That is because when you wait on an intercept, you don't just get the `response`, you get both `request` and `response` as two parts of one object.

Use destructuring to correctly reference the response.

This gets you correct data:

```js
cy.wait('@startApplication').then(({request, response}) => {  
  cy.wrap(response.body.applicationId).as('applicationId')
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. When I run Cypress test it's still looped in forever-loading state. The only thing that changed is that "response" is highlighted in my IDE as an error ( in 2nd line of your code )
 cy.wrap(response.body.applicationId).as('applicationId')

but now the typescript error points out to different issue:
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: I just mention it because it's an obvious mistake (if you look at the docs) and without changing that, you are going nowhere fast.

Comment: It seems like this does not help, as @hower89 mentioned

Comment: Sadly, that's pretty much all that can be said - the question lacks any other clues.

Comment: This is correct, take a look at the [Interception type](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/38bd1bb0488d2c6c36b090e3a4b13d67293320b7/packages/net-stubbing/lib/external-types.ts#L268) - there is no `body` property, but there is `request` and `response`.